# Does the sqrtPricex96 on the Uniswap V3 swap-event represent the average price paid by the swapper, or the new price of the pool after swap?

Tags: uniswapv3, amm

`sqrtPricex96` on a Uniswap V3 swap-event can be used to calculate the `token1/token0` price.

I'm not asking how to do this conversion. Instead I'm asking which `token1/token0` price does this represent?

1. the average price paid by the swapper
2. the new price of (the first concentrated available liquidity) of the pool *after* swap

Thinking 2. since 1. can be calculated by `amount0/amount1` from the same swap-event. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqrtPricesX96 for a evetn swaap is the price of the pool after swap

Here a screenshot from uniswap doc:
[image]

See docs from Uniswap https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/core/interfaces/pool/IUniswapV3PoolEvents#swap